# solve differential equation using given substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following equation by making substitution
$$y=xz^n \text{ or } z=\frac{y}{x^n}$$
and choosing a convenient value of n.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{2y}{x} +\frac{x^3}{y} +x\tan\frac{y}{x^2}$$

I thought it can be solved in 2 ways
1.making it exact differential equation
2.making it linear differential equation
But I do not understand when i will do substitution.
Please help me solve this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the ODE has the term $x\tan\dfrac{y}{x^2}$ present, so it is obviously to choose $n=2$ .

Let $z=\dfrac{y}{x^2}$ ,

Then $y=x^2z$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x^2\dfrac{dz}{dx}+2xz$

$\therefore x^2\dfrac{dz}{dx}+2xz=2xz+\dfrac{x}{z}+x\tan z$

$x^2\dfrac{dz}{dx}=x\left(\dfrac{1}{z}+\tan z\right)$

$\dfrac{dx}{x}=\dfrac{z}{z\tan z+1}dz$

$\int\dfrac{dx}{x}=\int\dfrac{z}{z\tan z+1}dz$

$\int\dfrac{dx}{x}=\int\dfrac{z\cos z}{z\sin z+\cos z}dz$

$\int\dfrac{dx}{x}=\int\dfrac{d(z\sin z+\cos z)}{z\sin z+\cos z}$

$\ln x=\ln(z\sin z+\cos z)+c$

$x=C(z\sin z+\cos z)$

$x=C\left(\dfrac{y}{x^2}\sin\dfrac{y}{x^2}+\cos\dfrac{y}{x^2}\right)$

Answer (score 5):

Here is one approach (others may also be possible, but we will use your hint).

We are given:

$$\tag 1 \frac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{2y}{x} +\dfrac{x^3}{y} +x \tan \frac{y}{x^2}$$

Lets choose the substitution:

$$\tag 2 z = \dfrac{y}{x^2} \rightarrow y = x^2 z$$

Differentiating $(2)$ yields:

$$\tag 3 \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2x z + x^2 \dfrac{dz}{dx}$$

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$ yields:

$$\tag 4 \frac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{2 x^2 z}{x} +\dfrac{x^3}{x^2 z} +x \tan \frac{x^2 z}{x^2} = 2 x z + \dfrac{x}{z} +x \tan z$$

Now, since we have two expressions for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, we can equate $(3)$ and $(4)$, yielding:

$$2x z + x^2 \dfrac{dz}{dx} = 2 x z + \dfrac{x}{z} +x \tan z$$

Simplifying, yields:

$$x^2 \dfrac{dz}{dx} = \dfrac{x}{z} +x \tan z$$

Simplifying yields:

$$\dfrac{dz}{dx} = \dfrac{z \tan z + 1}{x z}$$

This can be written as:

$$\tag 5 \displaystyle \int\dfrac{z ~ dz}{z \tan z + 1} = \int \dfrac{dx}{x}$$

Now, you can integrate each side of $(5)$ and then substitute in for $z$ and you are done.

Upon integrating, you get:

$$ \ln(z \sin z + \cos z) = \ln x + c$$

You have an expression for $z$, substitute and you can simplify a bit.

Comment: What can be the other approach.How will I know what value of n to take.Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Excellent work, Amzoti! Another TU for U